# Pattern Matching with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, rubygems, pattern-matching

Im looking to match two strings and return a score, I don't care about order, just the percentage of character matches.. I was looking at the 'string_score' gem but it cares about order.. as can seen by my test ... any suggestions on a better approach?

```
require 'string_score/ext/string'

"JAMES DOWNY".downcase.score("Downy, James".downcase)

#=> 0

"JAMES DOWNY".downcase.score("James Downy".downcase)
#=> 1


"JAMES DOWNY".downcase.score("James, Downy".downcase)

# w the comma
#=> 0
```

Comment: `"just the percentage of character matches"` can you elaborate on that? you mean the amount characters matched (single characters) or you mean individual words (separated by spaces) or you mean the whole expression into a larger one?

Comment: Well, aren't the first and second case not the same anyways because they have a comma?  And of course order will matter, since that determines whether they are equal or not.

Comment: sure, I'm going to look for characters matching.. it would be nice to recognized words versus non-words but that's pretty advanced... just keeping it simple here..

Comment: that's right, the comma stops them from matching, I would like to discount the match percentage because of the comma but not completely discount the other matching characters...

Comment: I personally think you need a different approach.  Do you basically want to count the letter in common and divide that by the length to get a percentage?

Comment: I think that would be a good start, thoughts?

Comment: It depends since the words could be different lengths.  I am going to fiddle around with some code now.

Comment: If I can give some advice, I would like into using `scan` instead. You could use it like this:`"JAMES DOWNY".scan(/?=JAMES/).length`

Comment: I looked at a few other gems, specifically the 'text' gem, I just found the 'amatch' gem which looks somewhat promising, will play with it for a bit and comment again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I looked around, specifically at the "string_score", "scorer", and "text" gems. Those weren't cutting it for this particular question. I decided to go with the "amatch" gem.

This was my made up code for checking the consistency between two strings.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scorer'
require 'amatch'

include Amatch

class String
    def order_downcase
        self.chars.sort_by(&:downcase).join.downcase
    end
end

def goodmatch?(check_string,base_string)
    x = JaroWinkler.new(basestring.order_downcase)
    x.match(check_string.order_downcase)
end
```

It's still not perfect though. For example if I do goodmatch?("one","two") it returns 0.0. I believe this is too low, it should be around 10% or something because of the "o" in both words. **I will give the answer and an up vote to someone who can better this solution.**